# .NET Core - Select.Pdf append existing pdf

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using Select.PDF in my .NET Core API.

I want to append an existing PDF to my generated PDF.

I was looking to docs and I found that PdfDocument can be initilizated by String Path.

Here:

https://selectpdf.com/docs/T_SelectPdf_PdfDocument.htm

But, I only have access to this one ctor:

https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/T_SelectPdf_PdfDocument.htm

This is because I'm using Select.PDF.NetCore? I can't use the other one.

Anyone help?

Comment: From the docs: "SelectPdf Html To Pdf Converter for .NET - Free Community Edition is a subset of SelectPdf", bite the  bullet and use the other other library.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the new PDF file with the previous PDF file to meet your needs.

I find sample code in official site, hope it will help you. [And you can click the button in this page.](https://selectpdf.com/demo-mvc/PdfMerge)

[image]